# Partitioning a table in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table which as around 5 million records, all columns in the table are string.  Sample columns: First_Name, Last_Name, Address.

My requirement is to have the rows divided into fixed number of partitions (say 100) while making sure that data is sorted by first_name and same first_name is available only in one partitions.

Comment: Can you tell us more about _why_ you have these requirements? Will the files still be used in Amazon Athena, or will they be processed elsewhere and that other system needs the files split in this way? It _is_ possible to bucket into a given number of files, but there is no provision for sorting -- hence my question.

Comment: We have a downstream application which expects data in sorted fashion and same not appearing in other file. Requirement for partitioning is due to the fact we can run multiple instances of downstream application.

Comment: There is a capability in Amazon Athena called [bucketing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/bucketing-vs-partitioning.html) that can split data across multiple files. Unlike **partitioning**, it creates a fixed number of buckets with data evenly spread between them (presumably on a hash basis). However, I don't know whether the data in each file is sorted. You would need to do some experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Is Athena reading the files from S3 OR Glue Data catalog ?

Assuming Athena is reading the files stored in S3 then you will have to sort and group the data first ( either by using Lambda/ Glue/EMR ) and then store it into S3 while creating partitions on the basis of first_name( s3://customer/data/first_name). By doing this the data will be sorted and all the same first name will be present in one partition.